# Adding a new module to current GWT project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am currently working on a GWT (version 2.8) project (NO MAVEN). I need to add a some new functionalities to the project with same Entry point (those should be access via the same application). But Those have separate business process from the current application. I don't need to load both in same time (if possible).
I have gone through [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules). I added a new module to the current project, but I have no idea to run newly added module.
Is `adding a module` the only one solution other than implementing those inside the current project or are there any other solutions ?

Comment: I need to implement two project with same entry point. Those two should be load separately. Is that possible in GWT?

Comment: Why do you want a single EntryPoint when things are mutually exclusive?

Comment: Adding a new modules give you a html and css file in the war folder and new packages in the project source folder. Adding RPC calls get a bit fiddly. You can share source from other packages client and server side. Client side use inherits-name in the gwt.xml file, were server side just imports the classes. Switching modules is either via Window.Location.assign or embedded in a Frame.

Comment: Not 100% what the question is. You could add a new module or use code splits or both, if you want to keep things separate.

Answer (score -2):

Inside EntryPoint class, you will get onlodeModule method

```
    @Override
public void onModuleLoad() {}
```

Inside this method you can call Async call like below

```
urAsync.callUrModuleMethod(input paramete1,input1,new AsyncCallback<UrDTOClass>(){
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                caught.getMessage();
            }
           @Override
            public void onSuccess(DTO result) {
             // here you can do your logic based on result
```

}

Comment: I did;t get your answer clear. what is urAsync.callUrModuleMethod(input paramete1,input1,new AsyncCallback<UrDTOClass>()).

Comment: GWT provides RPC mechanism to call server side code. If you are creating new module it means you will write new service for that module. So to call new module service method you need call like above.